# Data Source Name not found?

Tags: vb.net, odbc, connection-string, informix, dsn

I'm working on vb.net and trying to connect to a Informix database.
Both the system and the server are in 64-bit mode and the file DSN is from the 64-bit ODBC Data Sources.
The string is something like this: `DRIVER={IBM INFORMIX ODBC DRIVER (64-bit)};UID=userid;PWD=password;DATABASE=database;HOST=host;SERVER=server;SERVICE=9088;PROTOCOL=onsoctcp;CLIENT_LOCALE=en_US.CP1252;DB_LOCALE=en_US.819`

It returns this error:

> ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified.

I've already checked the name of the driver and it's correct, and the driver is installed correctly, as I have used it before with no problems.
Here's the code I'm trying to run, it's just a connection to the database which has worked for me before:

```
Imports System.Data.Odbc

Public Class Form1

    Dim x As New OdbcConnection

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim constr As String = "DRIVER={IBM INFORMIX ODBC DRIVER (64-bit)};UID=uid;PWD=passwd;DATABASE=database;HOST=host;SERVER=server;SERVICE=9088;PROTOCOL=onsoctcp;CLIENT_LOCALE=en_US.CP1252;DB_LOCALE=en_US.819"
        Try
            x.ConnectionString = constr
            x.Open()
            x.Close()
            Console.WriteLine("Connection Succesful")
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine("Connection Unsuccesful: " & ex.Message & Environment.NewLine & "Check input data")
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I've no idea how VB.NET and so on work, so if these sound like the raving maunderings of a sleep-deprived dipsomaniac, it's not too far off the truth (but I've fallen behind on the alcohol consumption).  It sounds as if the Microsoft ODBC Driver Manager has no idea about where or what the Informix ODBC Driver is — as if such drivers have to be registered somehow and the relevant step has not been taken for the Informix ODBC driver.  I've no idea whether that's an installation failure or something else. I can spell Windows — L, I, N, U, X, … whaddya mean, that's 'wrong'?

Answer (score 0):

I think your application is 64 bit where you installed and configured 32 bit ODBC driver, or vice versa.

If you have Informix driver installed then in ODBC Driver Manager configure DSN (of course with successful connection testing) and try to use DSN with much simpler ConnectionString like:

```
test_odbc('DSN=ifx_test; Uid=username; Pwd=password;')
```

You can also see my Python recipes that show available ODBC sources: https://code.activestate.com/recipes/578782-printing-list-of-odbc-data-sources/?in=user-186902

You can run it with 32 bit and 64 bit Python interpreter (I prefer ActiveState which comes with `odbc` module) and see what DSN are available for each environment.

Answer (score 0):

Just solved it. The debugger chose to work on X86 for some reason